# Emitting LaTeX a “token” at a time, handling superscripts

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I am outputting LaTeX from another source language, but one that only gives me things a source-token at a time.  Thus, I may get a token corresponding to “begin superscript” and then I will later get one corresponding to “end superscript”.

I used to have

```
\newcommand{\mybeginsup}{\begin{math}{}\sp\bgroup\tt}
\newcommand{\myendsup}{\egroup\end{math}}
```

(The `\tt` is the way I want my superscripts to style, and I hope it’s irrelevant.)

The problem with this is that it doesn’t handle nested superscripts.  My guess it that this causes a nesting of `\begin{math}` commands, and that it is this that causes the “Bad math environment delimiter.” error messages.

So, how should I do this?

I did try:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{embeddedmaths}
\renewcommand{\mybeginsup}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{embeddedmaths} = 0}%
{\addtocounter{embeddedmaths}{1}\begin{math}}{}\sp\bgroup\tt}
\renewcommand{\myendsup}{%
\egroup\addtocounter{embeddedmaths}{-1}%
\ifthenelse{\value{embeddedmaths} = 0}{\end{math}}{}}
```

to try to count the number of times I had entered math mode, but this gives

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
```

So now I’m stuck.

Comment: Probably missing a `\newcounter{embeddedmaths}` somewhere.

Comment: Gack.  Yes, the error is slightly different if I include the `\newcounter`.  I’ll update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could box the superscript content, since you know it will have to be in `\scriptstyle`:

[image: Grouping superscripts for processing later]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\supbox}% Superscript box
\newcommand{\bsup}{\begin{lrbox}{\supbox}$\tt\scriptstyle}% Superscript begin
\newcommand{\esup}{$\end{lrbox}{}^{\usebox{\supbox}}}% Superscript end
\begin{document}
$x^{\mathtt{2 5 4 a}}$ \quad % Traditional input
$x\bsup 2 5 4 a\esup$ % "Tokenized" input
\end{document}
```

Also note that defining a command beginning with `\end` causes problems with LaTeX, since it is usually associated with an environment. As such, I've used `\bsup` and `\esup`.

Comment: Thanks!  Your example doesn’t demonstrate it, but this also handles nested superscripts, such as

    $x\bsup 2\bsup 3\esup\esup$

Comment: Ah. What about including within an alltt environment?  If I do `\begin{alltt}
x\bsup{} 2\bsup{} 3\esup{}\esup{}
\end{alltt}` I get a `Missing $ inserted` error.

Comment: To answer my own follow-up question: the problem is the `\scriptstyle`, and/or the `$`.  I've changed your solution to have `\begin{lrbox}{\supbox}\tt\scriptsize` for the begin, and to `\end{lrbox}${}^{\usebox{\supbox}}$}` for the end. This works, and given the constraint of being inside an alltt, is perhaps as good as can be done.  Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: @MichaelNorrish: Sure; it seems like you don't even know whether you're in math mode or not. This was not clear from the start. Also note that nesting the superscripts works, but will leave you with a fixed superscript size however deep you go. LaTeX actually resizes superscripts of a superscript (to `\scriptscriptstyle`). Not sure whether this is an additional problem you might have.

Comment: Yeah, the fixed `\scriptsize` is a compromise I'm willing to make.  It’s true that I don't know if I will be in math-mode or not (in fact, the expectation is that I _won’t_ be).  Is it worth re-editing the original question to make this clear?

Answer (score 3):

the "shorthand" forms for `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` can help you here (stealing Werner's example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bsup}{^\bgroup}
\newcommand{\esup}{\egroup}
\begin{document}
$x^{\mathtt{2^{678} 5 4 a}}$ \quad % Traditional input
$x\bsup 2 \bsup 6 7 8 \esup 5 4 a\esup$ % "Tokenized" input
\end{document}
```

works without having to specify a size, so it handles multiple levels of superscripts:

[image: demonstration of tokenized superscript output]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid problems with nested math use `\ensuremath{...}` the standard latex command for going in to math mode if you are not already in it.

Alternatively if this isn't really math and you are just using math mode to get the superscript functionality (which seems likely if you want monospaced text) use `\textsuperscript` instead

Comment: The issue with `\ensuremath` is that I don’t have access to all of its argument at once (hence the “token at a time”).  I didn’t test very extensively but attempting, for example,

    `\newcommand{\squared}{\ensuremath\bgroup{}^2\egroup}

    \begin{alltt}
    x\squared
    \end{alltt}`

fails.

Putting `\textsuperscript` in for `\ensuremath` and getting rid of `{}^2` fails in the same way, sadly.

Comment: you can't use bgroup/egroup to delimit TeX macro arguments you need to use real braces, however what's to stop you emitting `\ensuremath{` at the start and `}` at the end (or similarly with `\textsuperscript` ).

Comment: Yes, you’re right.  The only issue with that would be my desire to introduce an extra layer of indirection, so that instead of mapping directly to `\ensuremath{\sp` for beginning a superscript, I’d like to be able to map to `\mybeginsup{}`.  But then I don’t know how to define `\mybeginsup` to have a body of `\ensuremath{\sp` because of the unbalanced braces.  I do admit this is quibbling over niceties!